# Grails, GORM, MongoDB: discriminator column value is ignored

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy, grails-orm, discriminator

I'm working on a Grails project, and I want to use GORM in order to read/write documents in a MongoDB. I have a specific scenario I want to implement, and I've been trying to make this work for 2-3 days now, but I can't find out what I'm doing wrong. I've read Grails documentation, many related posts on the web, but still nothing.

For the sake of simplicity I'm working on a simple enough scenario, which is the following:

I have 4 Domain classes:

**Someone.groovy**

```
class Someone {

    static mapWith = 'mongo'

    static embedded = ['animal']

    static constraints = {}

    String name

    Animal animal
}
```

**Animal.groovy**

```
class Animal {

    static mapWith = 'mongo'

    static mapping = {
        discriminator column: "type"
    }

    static belongsTo = Someone

    static constraints = {}
}
```

**Dog.groovy**

```
class Dog extends Animal {

    static mapWith = 'mongo'

    String dogName

    static mapping = {
        discriminator value: "dog"
    }

    static belongsTo = Someone

    static constraints = {}
}
```

**Cat.groovy**

```
class Cat extends Animal {

    static mapWith = 'mongo'

    String catName

    static mapping = {
        discriminator value: "cat"
    }

    static belongsTo = Someone

    static constraints = {}
}
```

Now, in a Service class, called **`CrudService`**, I have a method, e.g. **`foo()`**, and in that method I create a new **`Someone`** object, and save it to my Mongo database.

```
Someone someone = new Someone(name: "A name", animal: new Dog(dogName: "Azor"))
someone.save(flush: true)
```

When I check my mongoDB collection to see what was saved, I see:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong(21), 
    "animal" : { 
        "_class" : "Dog", 
        "dogName" : "Azor" 
    }, 
    "name" : "A name", 
    "version" : 0 
}
```

So, as you can see, the document was saved, but the discriminator column name (and values) were completely ignored. The document was saved with the value **`"_class"`** as the column name (which is the default discriminator column name) and the Class name (in this case **Dog**) as its value.

Can anyone please help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Is there a chance that the discriminator feature of GORM, works correctly for RDBMS but not for NoSQL databases?

(Currently I'm also looking at Morphia in order to see whether it can provide a solution to my problem, but I would prefer to use GORM since it is the default ORM for Grails).

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: I have a feeling that discriminator may not be additive, so your sub classes are replacing your column definition

Comment: @tim, thanks for the comment. Do you know if I can do something about it? the thing is that, by looking at the documentation http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Database%20Mapping/discriminator.html, I get the impression that what I've done, should work.

Comment: Hi @kostasg, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Hi @ilPittiz, to be honest, I don't even remember how we solved that back then :)